# Eating cherry tomatoes daily - Healthy?

Tags: diet

Over the years I have accumulated some extra body mass that I want to get rid of. I currently weigh almost 104kg at 1.85m.

To do this I have started exercising again and I am slowly adjusting my diet. First stage is removing most crap from my diet and introduce a low calorie breakfast.

For the last couple of weeks I eat 250g of cherry tomatoes and some other veg like half a cucumber, some radishes or some carrots. I find it tasty, it doesn't bore me (yet), I get lots af fluids (or at least I piss more and more often) and it keeps me satisfied till at least lunch time.

I wash the tomatoes before consuming, aiming to remove any pesticides (or other surface contaminents).

My question is: **Assuming I get enough macro- and micro nutrients in other meals, are there any short- or longterm health risks known to eating 250g of cherry tomatoes daily?**

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you asking whether eating 1/4 kilo of tomatoes daily has health hazards?  That could be googled to give you starting information to use when asking this question.  Or is the question whether just tomatoes and vegetables for breakfast is sufficient nutrition?  That depends on how much and what you're eating - and there are many schools of thought on breakfast nutrition.

Comment: I have rephrased my question. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: These nutritional questions usually get no answer because it is difficult to answer them. No study with a significant number of participants has been done to test the healthiness of eating cherry tomatoes daily. The only thing we can do is check whether substances none to cause health issues are present in a cherry tomato and whether they are present in a multitude that would actually impose a risk. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Narusan that is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can answer this myself now.

After ~3 weeks I started having problems with my intestines. My stool got very soft, sometimes more like diarrhoea. So I stopped eating tomatoes.
Ik took about 2 weeks for things to normalize again.

So I guess moderation is in place here. 1 or 2 times a week shouldn't be a problem, but don't overdo it.